# JTree: Can someone figure out that whats wrong with this Code

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtree

I am developing a small desktop application in Net beans. I drag and drop a `JTree` on my `JFrame` and now i want to fill the node hierarchy of this this `JTree` dynamically. For this i wrote a method which return me `DefaultMutableTreeNode` object. Now i again create tree with this object but the tree still shows old (default) nodes:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode root = createJTreeNodes();
jTree1 = new JTree(root);
jTree1.repaint();
jTree1.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
```

Could any one guide that what i need to change, in order to populate tree dynamically?

Comment: why can't you set model to existing jTree1 (using setModel)? Why are you recreating it? Also iirc, you can use custom code in netbeans GUI designer as "post construct", where you can initialize the jtree model.

Comment: @UsmanSaleem: i tried the setModel () method but it takes the object of TreeModel type whereas i have object of DefaultMutableTreeNode
I am sorry, i am new to java, so plz guide the right way of doing this

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835962/how-to-assign-defaultmutabletreenode-to-jtree - if a tool hinders you more than it helps, drop it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could any one guide that what i need to change, in order to populate tree dynamically?

A couple of different options:

```
DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel)tree.getModel();
DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)model.getRoot();
root.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("another_child"));
model.reload(root);
```

or

```
DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();
DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getRoot();
model.insertNodeInto(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("another_child"), root, root.getChildCount());
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to remove all the nodes in JTree which are added by netbeans by default.

```
DefaultTreeModel model=(DefaultTreeModel)jTree1.getModel();
model.setRoot(null);
```

Now create new root and add all the elements you want and use the above code to set the new root.